# stream from thermal camera (ip camera) on python , connection error

Tags: python, opencv, ip-camera, imaging

i want to stream from a thermal camera, usually it export  its frames as gray scale frames
the thermal camera is an IP camera , i tried different codes and package but with no output.
when i change the code a little bit to view from a USB camera it works normally, so any help please.
this is the code i have tried :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages')
import Tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
i=0

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('thermal image')
var = tk.IntVar()
width, height = 800, 600
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.open("http://169.254.110.119/")

left_label = tk.Label(window)
left_label.pack(side="left")
right_label = tk.Label(window)
right_label.pack(side="right")

def show_frame():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    print frame
    if frame != None:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        img = Image.fromarray(frame)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        left_label.imgtk = imgtk
        left_label.configure(image=imgtk)
        left_label.after(10, show_frame)

show_frame()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: when printing frame , it just giving me None . so no frame is grapped from the camera

Comment: You need to check the return values of functions you call so you find out ASAP if there were any problems, and, if so, where.

Comment: cap.read() is supposed to return if there is an error and the frame itself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the image from the websitre is not being grabbed in the code, what worked for me was

```
img_requested = requests.get(url)
img_arr = np.array(bytearray(img_requested.content), dtype=np.uint8)
frame = cv2.imdecode(img_arr, -1)
```

And there you would get the frame (color picures/video).Keep in mind that you need to import requests and numpy as np.

It is important if you are using IP Webcam that you do not forget to write the '/shot.jpg'
at the end of the url, like this: 'http://190.160.0.0:8080/shot.jpg', so that it effectivelly grabs the image.